# Need Hints for using Java into MRI Ruby application

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, passenger, rjb

I need some hints.

I have application which is builded on MRI Ruby (1.9.3) + Passenger

Now this application is needed to extend with "Apache POI" (http://poi.apache.org/) functionality. "Apache POI" is Java API for Microsoft Documents.

During investigation time I tested:

- "Apache POI" + JRuby. This combination worked very well.
- "Apache POI" + rjb (a bridge between Ruby and Java) + MRI Ruby. This combination worked very well. But during investigation time I various comments that this combination could have some problems work together with Passenger. (I not tested yet)

If "Apache POI + rjb + MRI Ruby + Passenger" combination will not work what possibilities/hints you all can provide to me to get "Apache POI" inside my application?

My opinions:

- Create small JRuby application (support Apache POI), then using REST APIs make connection between MRI Ruby application and JRuby application.

Comment: Do you need Java only to create Excel spreadsheets? If that's the case you may need to change the subject..

Answer (score 0):

If you need Java to deal with Excel shreadsheets only, you may want to consider pure Ruby ways to create an Excel instead of involving Java.

The simplest is to generate Excel XML like I've done for our prod app: https://gist.github.com/1252406 .

Another way is to use spreadsheet gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Apache POI + rjb + MRI Ruby + Passenger" you need to configur Passenger to restart after each request.

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_making_the_application_restart_after_each_request